# Measuring VR view on the web with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-cardboard

I am interested in measuring user behaviour of VR views that will be embedded in our website using Google Analytics. I want to see if users are engaging with the VR's. I am planning on doing basic tracking where I capture the URL of the VR and the page it was played on in an event label, set an event action to "VR Play" and set the event category to "VR View".

I am curious to know if anyone is doing more advanced tracking than this, and exactly what they are measuring and how.